# GROUP BY INTERVALS

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, average

I want to take the average of multiple rows of table and insert them into a view:

My table:

- Date(datetime)
- Period(int) -- Half-hour
- Price(decimal(18,2)

Sample data:

```
Date     | Period | Price 
---------+--------+---------
07-12-17 |  47    | 10 
07-12-17 |  48    | 20
07-12-17 |   1    | 30
07-12-17 |   2    | 40
07-12-17 |   3    | 50
07-12-17 |   4    | 60
07-12-17 |   5    | 70
07-12-17 |   6    | 80 
07-12-17 |   7    | 10
07-12-17 |   8    | 10
07-12-17 |   9    | 10
07-12-17 |  10    | 10
07-12-17 |  11    | 20
07-12-17 |  12    | 20
07-12-17 |  13    | 20
07-12-17 |  14    | 20
```

My periods are half hours go from 1-48 and I want to take the average price of intervals of 8 periods and assign that price to all 8 periods in the set. Because of the time difference, I start with half-hour 47 instead of 1:

The intervals:

```
[48-6], [7-14], [15-22], [23-30], [31-38], [39-46]
```

I want the resulting view to look like:

```
Date     | Period | Price 
---------+--------+---------
07-12-17 |   47   | 45 
07-12-17 |   48   | 45
07-12-17 |    1   | 45
07-12-17 |    2   | 45
07-12-17 |    3   | 45
07-12-17 |    4   | 45
07-12-17 |    5   | 45
07-12-17 |    6   | 45
07-12-17 |    7   | 15
07-12-17 |    8   | 15
07-12-17 |    9   | 15
07-12-17 |   10   | 15
07-12-17 |   11   | 15
07-12-17 |   12   | 15
07-12-17 |   13   | 15
07-12-17 |   14   | 15
```

I have not been able to come up with a complete query, but I am thinking it has to be GROUP BY and maybe with a HAVING Statement.

Hope you can help!

Comment: c.f. [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to getting better answers.

Comment: Do you want a view or an update script?

Comment: Only a view is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done very easily and efficiently using window functions.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (dt datetime2(0), Period int, Price money);
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('2017-12-06', 39, 90),
('2017-12-06', 40, 90),
('2017-12-06', 41, 90),
('2017-12-06', 42, 90),
('2017-12-06', 43, 90),
('2017-12-06', 44, 90),
('2017-12-06', 45, 90),
('2017-12-06', 46, 90),

('2017-12-06', 47, 10),
('2017-12-06', 48, 20),
('2017-12-07',  1, 30),
('2017-12-07',  2, 40),
('2017-12-07',  3, 50),
('2017-12-07',  4, 60),
('2017-12-07',  5, 70),
('2017-12-07',  6, 80),

('2017-12-07',  7, 10),
('2017-12-07',  8, 10),
('2017-12-07',  9, 10),
('2017-12-07', 10, 10),
('2017-12-07', 11, 20),
('2017-12-07', 12, 20),
('2017-12-07', 13, 20),
('2017-12-07', 14, 20),

('2017-12-07', 15, 40),
('2017-12-07', 16, 40),
('2017-12-07', 17, 40),
('2017-12-07', 18, 40),
('2017-12-07', 19, 30),
('2017-12-07', 20, 30),
('2017-12-07', 21, 30),
('2017-12-07', 22, 30);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    dt
    ,Period
    ,Price
    ,DATEADD(minute, (Period-1)*30 + 60, dt) as d2
    ,DATEDIFF(hour, '2001-01-01', DATEADD(minute, (Period-1)*30 + 60, dt)) / 4 as d3
    ,AVG(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY 
        DATEDIFF(hour, '2001-01-01', DATEADD(minute, (Period-1)*30 + 60, dt)) / 4) AS AvgPrice
FROM @T AS MyTable
ORDER BY dt, Period;
```

I included intermediary results `d2` and `d3` in the output to help understand the formula in `PARTITION BY`.

**Result**

```
+---------------------+--------+-------+---------------------+-------+----------+
|         dt          | Period | Price |         d2          |  d3   | AvgPrice |
+---------------------+--------+-------+---------------------+-------+----------+
| 2017-12-06 00:00:00 |     39 | 90.00 | 2017-12-06 20:00:00 | 37103 | 90.00    |
| 2017-12-06 00:00:00 |     40 | 90.00 | 2017-12-06 20:30:00 | 37103 | 90.00    |
| 2017-12-06 00:00:00 |     41 | 90.00 | 2017-12-06 21:00:00 | 37103 | 90.00    |
| 2017-12-06 00:00:00 |     42 | 90.00 | 2017-12-06 21:30:00 | 37103 | 90.00    |
| 2017-12-06 00:00:00 |     43 | 90.00 | 2017-12-06 22:00:00 | 37103 | 90.00    |
| 2017-12-06 00:00:00 |     44 | 90.00 | 2017-12-06 22:30:00 | 37103 | 90.00    |
| 2017-12-06 00:00:00 |     45 | 90.00 | 2017-12-06 23:00:00 | 37103 | 90.00    |
| 2017-12-06 00:00:00 |     46 | 90.00 | 2017-12-06 23:30:00 | 37103 | 90.00    |
| 2017-12-06 00:00:00 |     47 | 10.00 | 2017-12-07 00:00:00 | 37104 | 45.00    |
| 2017-12-06 00:00:00 |     48 | 20.00 | 2017-12-07 00:30:00 | 37104 | 45.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |      1 | 30.00 | 2017-12-07 01:00:00 | 37104 | 45.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |      2 | 40.00 | 2017-12-07 01:30:00 | 37104 | 45.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |      3 | 50.00 | 2017-12-07 02:00:00 | 37104 | 45.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |      4 | 60.00 | 2017-12-07 02:30:00 | 37104 | 45.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |      5 | 70.00 | 2017-12-07 03:00:00 | 37104 | 45.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |      6 | 80.00 | 2017-12-07 03:30:00 | 37104 | 45.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |      7 | 10.00 | 2017-12-07 04:00:00 | 37105 | 15.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |      8 | 10.00 | 2017-12-07 04:30:00 | 37105 | 15.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |      9 | 10.00 | 2017-12-07 05:00:00 | 37105 | 15.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |     10 | 10.00 | 2017-12-07 05:30:00 | 37105 | 15.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |     11 | 20.00 | 2017-12-07 06:00:00 | 37105 | 15.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |     12 | 20.00 | 2017-12-07 06:30:00 | 37105 | 15.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |     13 | 20.00 | 2017-12-07 07:00:00 | 37105 | 15.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |     14 | 20.00 | 2017-12-07 07:30:00 | 37105 | 15.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |     15 | 40.00 | 2017-12-07 08:00:00 | 37106 | 35.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |     16 | 40.00 | 2017-12-07 08:30:00 | 37106 | 35.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |     17 | 40.00 | 2017-12-07 09:00:00 | 37106 | 35.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |     18 | 40.00 | 2017-12-07 09:30:00 | 37106 | 35.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |     19 | 30.00 | 2017-12-07 10:00:00 | 37106 | 35.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |     20 | 30.00 | 2017-12-07 10:30:00 | 37106 | 35.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |     21 | 30.00 | 2017-12-07 11:00:00 | 37106 | 35.00    |
| 2017-12-07 00:00:00 |     22 | 30.00 | 2017-12-07 11:30:00 | 37106 | 35.00    |
+---------------------+--------+-------+---------------------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Think this is the right way to go. But using your code I get different AvgPrice value for each period.

Comment: @Deldar22, please extend the sample data in the question to illustrate the problem. So far, my query seems to generate expected result.

Comment: You just saved me a lifetime!

Comment: What would I have to change if the interval was starting from 1 to 48 instead of 47?

Comment: @Deldar22, change the shift `+60` to some other number of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The code sample below should get you close to where you need to be. I was not sure from your question how you planned on setting up your groups.  You will definitely want to use a cross apply if you are using a view. This can be done even more simply with a stored procedure.  For more info on Cross Apply, see section L, here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql.

```
CREATE VIEW MyTableAveragePrices
AS
SELECT mt.Date, mt.Period, mtAverageGroup.AveragePrice, 
    CASE
       WHEN mtAvg.Period IN () THEN 'Period Group 1'
       WHEN mtAvg.Period IN () THEN 'Period Group 2'
    END AS PeriodGroup
FROM MyTable mt
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
    SELECT 
        AVERAGE(mtAvg.Price) AveragePrice,
        CASE
           WHEN mtAvg.Period IN () THEN 'Period Group 1'
           WHEN mtAvg.Period IN () THEN 'Period Group 2'
        END AS PeriodGroup
    FROM MyTable mtAvg
    WHERE
        mt.PeriodGroup = PeriodGroup
    GROUP BY
        CASE
           WHEN mtAvg.Period IN () THEN 'Period Group 1'
           WHEN mtAvg.Period IN () THEN 'Period Group 2'
        END
    ) mtAverageGroup
GO
```